# run matlab script on python

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to run a matlab's script that calculates the area of a triangle on python.

Python version 2.7.11
Python script saved as triarea.py:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.triarea(nargout=0)
```

MATLAB version 2015b
Matlab script saved as triarea.m:

```
b = 5;
h = 3;
a = 0.5*(b.* h)
```

Running:
python triarea.py

But when I try to run the python file with the matlab script an error appears to the screen:

Segmentation fault: 11

And if I choose read more about the error:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                             000000000000000000 0 + 0
1   libpython2.7.dylib              0x0000000104271b17 PyEval_GetGlobals + 23
2   libpython2.7.dylib              0x0000000104295da2 PyImport_Import + 50
3   libpython2.7.dylib              0x0000000104295fd8 PyImport_ImportModule + 40
4   matlabengineforpython2_7.so     0x000000010392fcf7 initmatlabengineforpython2_7 + 23
```

I don't know what to do. Help please thank you!

Comment: You failed to mention that your use case is [exactly an example from the manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-user-script-and-function-from-python.html). This suggests that the problem is with your installation, not the program.